# Problems with weighted overlay on QGIS for Mac

Tags: qgis, saga, overlay, mac

I am a beginner on GIS seeking to finish a suitability analysis. For this I was planning to use 'vector to raster' tools as well as a 'weighted overlay analysis' to find the most suitable areas.

I was able to rasterize a vector layer in QGIS 2.14 Essen, using raster > conversion > rasterize.

However I can't find a way to do the weighted overlay analysis. All threads I've read says that SAGA plugin should have such a tool, but I cannot find SAGA in neither QGIS versions 2.14 or 2.18.

I have Mac OSx version Sierra. I have searched for weighted overlay tools on both QGIS 2.14 Essen and 2.18 Las Palmas without luck. I don't have time to downgrade my MacOS and hope the problem is not with Sierra compatibility.

How can I get the SAGA plugin to work? Or in case its impossible, what other solutions are there?